# Spring Batch with Paginated SOAP API as input data source

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-batch

I have a Paginated SOAP API from which I have to read data and process and write the data to a db using Spring Batch.
The API is a SOAP API and it takes the page number as an input:
`<pageNumber>1</pageNumber>` 
 
So I have created an `ItemReader` extending the `AbstractPagingItemReader` class provided by Spring Batch.


Inside the reader I am overriding the `doReadPage()` method and sending the `this.getPage() + 1` as the input to the SOAP API request. But every time the batch job is running the Reader is only reading the first page, though there are 20 other pages available to read from the API.
I tried to follow the structure of `JPAPagingItemReader` and use `this.getPage()` to determine the current page and go to the next page. 
This is how the Step looks like.

```
return stepBuilderFactory.get("processData").<InputModel, OutputModel>chunk(5)
            .reader(itemReader)
            .processor(processor)
            .writer(writer)
            .build();
```

This is how the Job is configured:

```
return jobBuilderFactory
            .get("chunksJob")
            .flow(step1(stepBuilderFactory, itemReader(), itemProcessor(), itemWriter()))
            .end()
            .build();
```

I am running the job in a scheduled manner

```
JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job,
                new JobParametersBuilder()
                        .addString("JOB_ID",
                                String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).toJobParameters());
        return jobExecution.getExitStatus().toString();
```

What am I doing wrong here, and what changes can I make in this so that each job execution reads all the available pages from the API.

Comment: Can you provide your `ItemReader` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without your ItemReader implementation, but some things to check...

1. Are you setting the pageSize when creating your ItemReader bean?  This defaults to 10.  If your web service returns less than 10 results and you haven't set the pageSize, that could be the problem.
2. Does your web service start with page 1 instead of page 0? The answer will determine if you should be using  `this.getPage() + 1` instead of `this.getPage()` in your `doReadPage()` method since `AbstractPagingItemReader` starts at page 0.
3. In your `doReadPage()` method, you should be replacing the `AbstractPagingItemReader results` list with the list of items returned from your web service

Comment: Thanks @httPants. The API was returning 5 results per page and the default page size in the Reader was set to 10. I have changed the API configuration to return 10 results, now it's reading every page.